# Xcode is not building to run apps on simulators , showing error of provisioning certificates

Tags: certificate, provisioning, xcode10

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlo6c.png)

I am a new to app development .in current phase I am learning how to make them using some tutorials . after using for few days , suddenly my project is not able to build and run the app on simulator . it's showing that provisioning profiles could not be created. I have tried everything and stuck for a day but nothing coming out to be correct.

error : failed to create provisioning certificate
There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.

Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'tour.holi-celebration0000000'.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if there are extra certificates in Keychain -> My Certificates.

I had similar problem once and it was fixed after removing unnecessary certificates from Keychain.